# How do I validate day and month?

Tags: php, html, css

I have both drop down lists for day and month but textbox for year. please go easy on me I'm a total noob in html, php or css. How do I check if its a valid date? e.g (No 31 April, Leap years) EDIT: This is for input of date of birth. I would like to check if their date of birth input is valid or not.

```
<select name="day">
                    <option value='0'>1
                    <option value='1'>2
                    <option value='2'>3
                    <option value='3'>4
                    <option value='4'>5
                    <option value='5'>6
                    <option value='6'>7
                    <option value='7'>8
                    <option value='8'>9
                    <option value='9'>10
                    <option value='10'>11
                    <option value='11'>12
                    <option value='12'>13
                    <option value='13'>14
                    <option value='14'>15
                    <option value='15'>16
                    <option value='16'>17
                    <option value='17'>18
                    <option value='18'>19
                    <option value='19'>20
                    <option value='20'>21
                    <option value='21'>22
                    <option value='22'>23
                    <option value='23'>24
                    <option value='24'>25
                    <option value='25'>26
                    <option value='26'>27
                    <option value='27'>28
                    <option value='28'>29
                    <option value='29'>30
                    <option value='30'>31
                    </select>
<select name="month">
                    <option value='0'>Jan
                    <option value='1'>Feb
                    <option value='2'>Mar
                    <option value='3'>Apr
                    <option value='4'>May
                    <option value='5'>Jun
                    <option value='6'>Jul
                    <option value='7'>Aug
                    <option value='8'>Sep
                    <option value='9'>Oct
                    <option value='10'>Nov
                    <option value='11'>Dec
                    </select>
<input type="text" name="Year" size="4" maxlength="4" value="Year"/>
```

Comment: why do you need validate you can get exact date of user in `php`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add in that this is for input of the user's date of birth.

Comment: @NicholasWong you need to generate no of days in every month

Comment: @sanojlawrence how do I do that? I'm a total noob at coding..

Comment: maybe useful: [checkdate — Validate a Gregorian date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php). Will allow some simple code that will stop a lot of the 'sillies'.

Comment: If you have a teacher, why not ask them instead of coming to SO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not validate but you can generate data and year

try this

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
         $(function() {
         $("#datepicker").datepicker();
         });
 </script>


  <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>
```

### UPDATED

Finally found solution to your question no plugin nothing just a code

```
          <select name="month" onChange="changeDate(this.options[selectedIndex].value);">
<option value="na">Month</option>
<option value="1">January</option>
<option value="2">February</option>
<option value="3">March</option>
<option value="4">April</option>
<option value="5">May</option>
<option value="6">June</option>
<option value="7">July</option>
<option value="8">August</option>
<option value="9">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option>
</select>
<select name="day" id="day">
<option value="na">Day</option>
</select>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function changeDate(i){
var e = document.getElementById('day');
while(e.length>0)
e.remove(e.length-1);
var j=-1;
if(i=="na")
k=0;
else if(i==2)
k=28;
else if(i==4||i==6||i==9||i==11)
k=30;
else
k=31;
while(j++<k){
var s=document.createElement('option');
var e=document.getElementById('day');
if(j==0){
s.text="Day";
s.value="na";
try{
e.add(s,null);}
catch(ex){
e.add(s);}}
else{
s.text=j;
s.value=j;
try{
e.add(s,null);}
catch(ex){
e.add(s);}}}}
y = 1993;
while (y-->1940){
var s = document.createElement('option');
var e = document.getElementById('year');
s.text=y;
s.value=y;
try{
e.add(s,null);}
catch(ex){
e.add(s);}}
</script>
```

Comment: It's a requirement to put day and month into dropdown lists and year into a textbox. Is there no way to validate?

Comment: Alright, the code works! but I need to have a textbox for my year input.. and it has to take into account leap years too.

Comment: hey what do i have to do to remove the year part in this?

Comment: @NicholasWong you need only date and month

Comment: @NicholasWong check updated code only date and day will be displayed

Answer (score 1):

Server-side, you can use the [checkdate](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.checkdate.php) function.

```
$month = intval($_POST["month"]);
$day = intval($_POST["day"]);
$year = intval($_POST["year"]);

if(checkdate($month, $day, $year) {
    // Date is correct
}
```

Client-side, you'll have to use the JavaScript language to check that.

Comment: How do I check using js language?

Comment: @NicholasWong, Validating 'client side' is 'useful' and will train 'users' but it must be validated at the 'destination' as well. All data must be validated by the 'business model' . I can assure you that it tries to ensure **everything** that it 'saves' is 'valid' or the 'state' of the information is marked appropriately. If there are no checks on the client. I assure you, there are lots of checks on the server.